# React Testing Library - query updated DOM

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a React app that has a component with a button.  That button click causes a call to my API(which will eventually be mocked) and retrieves back some data.  On retrieval of that data, a `ol` list of numbers gets updated by getting the class of `invalid` added to some of the numbers.  So I'm trying to test that functionality with React Testing Library.  And when I console out that list that *should* be updated after the API call, I'm not seeing any of the newly added `invalid` class names.

Here is my test:

```js
test('clicking yes and passing back only 2 valid batch numbers should show 2 valid, 2 invalid batch numbers in list', async () => {
    renderBatchListWithNumbers();
    const completeButton = screen.getByText('Complete');
    fireEvent.click(completeButton);
    const yesButton = screen.getByText('Yes');
    fireEvent.click(yesButton);
    // now we need to figure out mocking the API calls!!!
    let batchList = await screen.getByRole('list', {
        name: 'Batch Numbers',
    });
    const allItems = within(batchList);
    const items = allItems.getAllByRole('listitem');
    // console.log({ items });
    // const allItems = within(batchList);
    // const items = allItems.getAllByRole('listitem');
    items.forEach((li) => {
        console.log(li.className);
    });
});
```

And this is `renderBatchListWithNumbers`:

```js
const renderBatchListWithNumbers = () => {
    render(
        <AlertProvider template={AlertMUITemplate}>
            <BatchList
                formulaID={''}
                orderID={''}
                itemID={''}
                formulaResults={[]}
                batchNumbers={[
                    { BATCH_ID: '987654', ID: '78' },
                    { BATCH_ID: '261010', ID: '79' },
                    { BATCH_ID: '301967', ID: '80' },
                    { BATCH_ID: '445566', ID: '81' },
                ]}
                setBatchNumbers={() => {
                    // empty
                }}
                batchNumber={'5'}
                setBatchNumber={() => {
                    /* empty */
                }}
            />
        </AlertProvider>
    );
};
```

So I want to know if the API call is not working and therefore not updating the DOM or if the test is not correctly reading the updated DOM.

Comment: _call to my API(which will eventually be mocked)_ if your API isn't mocked yet, then maybe it's throwing an error when you run the test and that's why the `invalid` classes aren't added

Comment: OK, so the api call gets made on my button `onClick` in my app.  Do I need to explicity add that api call in my test, or does that just happen?

Comment: It's better if it "just happens on its own" when you click on the button. Because that way your test is more realistic from the user's perspective, it's more confident. Because the average user is unaware of API calls that happen in the background, they just know that they clicked a button and whoosh, something magical happened. [Here is a good article](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/stop-mocking-fetch) on how you should mock your API (in this example it's `fetch` but by using [msw](https://mswjs.io/) it doesn't matter what you're using to make network requests).

Comment: The test looks good. Does your component work as you expect when running the app?

Comment: @diedu  Yes, component works fine.  I just wanted to properly test it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the code for `BatchList` to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're waiting for the `Batch Numbers` list to be present, which is always present(I'm assuming), so the test continues immediately even when the API call hasn't been completed. Try using [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) instead to check items have the className you expect.

```
  await waitFor(() => {
    const items = allItems.getAllByRole("listitem");
    expect(
      items.filter((item) => item.className.includes("invalid")).length
    ).toBe(expectedInvalidItems);
  });
```

Comment: Hmm, well know all four list items have 'invalid' instead of 'valid', but only 2 items should be 'invalid' after state is updated from the API call.

Comment: @dmikester1, so now the test fails with an error that 4 not equals 2?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @dmikester1 You said the API is not mocked yet. Did you check the API is returning the values you need to have only two invalid items? I think it'd be good to start mocking your API, as Kapobajza mentioned in the comment, to have a determinate behavior in the test